# Ms-Access - IF checkbox = true THEN (Compile error)

Tags: ms-access

A Compile error occurs when i try this code allow a button to be pressed if the check boxes are true

```
Option Compare Database

Function CheckMyButton()
Me.Command414.Enabled = (Me.chk1 And Me.chk2 And Me.check4 And Me.chk3)
End Function

Private Sub chk1_AfterUpdate()
=CheckMyButton()
End Function

Private Sub chk2_AfterUpdate()
=CheckMyButton()
End Sub

Private Sub check4_AfterUpdate()
=CheckMyButton()
End Sub

Private Sub chk3_AfterUpdate()
=CheckMyButton()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=CheckMyButton()` doesn't go into the body of event procedures (in there you would use `Call CheckMyButton()` ).

`=CheckMyButton()` goes directly into the `AfterUpdate` property - in the property window of the form.

The point is to not have multiple event procedures that all do the same thing.

German Access here:

[image]

Comment: Ah it works, but when a new record is added it still allows me to press the button. only if i tick a text box/untick one will it make the button not clickable

Comment: Add the same to the `Current` event of the form.

Comment: How would i add a editable text box that shows my Nz (Dlookup) 
    Nz(DLookUp("Password","Employees","Username='" & 
    TempVars("EmployeeType2") & "'"),"")

Comment: That's a calculated field and that's never editable.

Comment: ah i see, i am looking to make an edit user form ( where the tempVar Username and password is stored) i dont know how i wold do this